# Text detection on images

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am a very new student on machine learning. I just wanted to ask what are possible ways to improve a method (Naive Bayes for example) to get better results classifying images into text or non-text images, instead of just inputing a x number of images and telling the system which have text and which do not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state of the art in such problems are deep neural networks with several convolutional layers. See [this article](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/imagenet.pdf) for an example of image classification using deep convolutional nets. Your problem (just determining if an image has text or not) is much easier than the general image classification problem the authors consider, so you'd probably get away with using a much simpler network architecture.

Nowadays you don't need to implement these things yourself, there are efficient and GPU-accelerated implementations freely available, for instance [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/), [Torch7](http://torch.ch/), [keras](http://keras.io/)...